# how to combine a members table with a players table under a logged in member?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am making a site where you need to register and then create a character to play with.
How  i can combine the tables i use from the register page with a table for the player, so that a player always gets his created character.

i have a table members that is user to  store the registered users
and a table players for the characters

i looked into the session_id but  from what i understand  i cant store data into a mysql table with that.

i also looked into adding the username and email from the members table to the players table on creation but i failed to so. i was thinking i could the  say if username and ID are the same in both tables user that player.

i am very new at all of this.

this is the register code

```
<?php
include_once 'db_connect.php';
include_once 'psl-config.php';

$error_msg = "";

$now = time();


if (isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['p'])) {
    // Sanitize and validate the data passed in
    $username = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'username', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $email = filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        // Not a valid email
        $error_msg .= '<p class="error">The email address you entered is not valid</p>';
    }

    $password = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'p', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    if (strlen($password) != 128) {
        // The hashed pwd should be 128 characters long.
        // If it's not, something really odd has happened
        $error_msg .= '<p class="error">Invalid password configuration.</p>';
    }

    // Username validity and password validity have been checked client side.
    // This should should be adequate as nobody gains any advantage from
    // breaking these rules.
    //

    $prep_stmt = "SELECT id FROM members WHERE email = ? LIMIT 1";
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($prep_stmt);

   // check existing email  
    if ($stmt) {
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $email);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();

        if ($stmt->num_rows == 1) {
            // A user with this email address already exists
            $error_msg .= '<p class="error">A user with this email address already exists.</p>';
                        $stmt->close();
        }
                $stmt->close();
    } else {
        $error_msg .= '<p class="error">Database error Line 39</p>';
                $stmt->close();
    }

    // check existing username
    $prep_stmt = "SELECT id FROM members WHERE username = ? LIMIT 1";
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($prep_stmt);

    if ($stmt) {
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $username);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();

                if ($stmt->num_rows == 1) {
                        // A user with this username already exists
                        $error_msg .= '<p class="error">A user with this username already exists</p>';
                        $stmt->close();
                }
                $stmt->close();
        } else {
                $error_msg .= '<p class="error">Database error line 55</p>';
                $stmt->close();
        }

    // TODO: 
    // We'll also have to account for the situation where the user doesn't have
    // rights to do registration, by checking what type of user is attempting to
    // perform the operation.

    if (empty($error_msg)) {
        // Create a random salt
        //$random_salt = hash('sha512', uniqid(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16), TRUE)); // Did not work
        $random_salt = hash('sha512', uniqid(mt_rand(1, mt_getrandmax()), true));

        // Create salted password 
        $password = hash('sha512', $password . $random_salt);


        // Insert the new user into the database
        // Add here wat you want to add into the database at account creation  

        if ($insert_stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO members (username, email, password, salt, accdate) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, now())")) {
            $insert_stmt->bind_param('ssss', $username, $email, $password, $random_salt);

            // Execute the prepared query.
            if (! $insert_stmt->execute()) {
                header('Location: ../error.php?err=Registration failure: INSERT');
            }
        }
        header('Location: ./register_success.php');
    }
}
```

can anyone point me in the right direction?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a lot to read, generally speaking though you would want to associate the user id on the user table with the character. ( user_id would be a foreign key on characters pointing to id on user table. both tables have a primary key of id which should be auto incremented ), you do then have to maintain the relationship so when they create the character you could insert the current logged in user_id into the table, if you want to limit them to one character you can make the column ( user_id ) unique.

for example ...

```
table user, 
id, name, login, password  etc...

table character
id, user_id, character_name, hp, etc..
```

then you can join on the tables like so

```
SELECT u.*, c.* FROM users AS u JOIN characters AS c ON u.id = c.user_id WHERE u.id = $user_id.
```

that would ( in theory ) give you all the records from the users table and characters table for the $user_id ( assuming they have records in both tables, use LEFT JOIN, if they don't or may not have a character record )

HERE is a good tutorial on some basic database relationships.

http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/sql-for-beginners-part-3-database-relationships--net-8561

Comment: so for me that would be: 
    SELECT m.*, p.* FROM members AS u JOIN players AS p ON m.id = p.user_id WHERE m.id = $user_id 

tables are members and players.

i should be able to get the $user_id into the session cookie and use it from there

i am not  sure how to do this but this will help me a lot
Thanks

Comment: Yea that is the basics of it, glad i could point you down the right road, the database is designed to do this type of thing.